# Distinct Join SQL with n number of Databases

Tags: sql, sql-server

May seem silly, but still working through SQL and I've hit my limitation on what I can write out.

Here is the scenario: I have many SQL Servers that have multiple databases in them. I need to search every database and if a table is there return the results then join those results all together with a secondary database.

I also need the database name that each of these tables live in.

Query #1 which returns the the data that is important

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    datafeed_id AS 'Datafeed ID', 
    MAX(start_time) AS 'Start Time', 
    MAX(end_time) AS 'End Time', 
    MAX(status_id) AS 'Status',
    MAX(DATEDIFF(mi, [start_time], [end_time])) AS 'Run Time'
FROM 
    dbo.tblDataFeedHistory
GROUP BY
    datafeed_id
```

Query #2 which returns the information Supporting Query1 that I need. Note I was calling each database out individually here but there could n databases

```
CREATE OR ALTER VIEW [vAllDatabasesDataFeedResult] 
AS
    SELECT
        Name = 'Instance',
        [datafeed_name], [status], [is_active]
    FROM 
        instance.dbo.tblDatafeed

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        Name = 'Instance1',
        [datafeed_name], [status], [is_active] 
    FROM
        Instance2.dbo.tblDataFeed;
```

What I'd like to see output from ALL databases in SQL IF they contain the table `dbo.tblDataFeed`

```
| Database Name | Datafeed_name | Is_active | Status | Start_time | End_Time | Status_id | Runtime
```

I'd prefer it return the results vice creating a new view.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This feels more like a database design and process question than a programming one. The fact you need a dynamic query to look across many instances of many databases of similar-structured tables suggest your setup is not well normalized and you may have runaway business logic that produces open-ended number of objects like tables even databases on the fly (which keeps DBAs up at night!). If you are lead architect, fix this before anything. Databases should be well-designed and planned productions, not constantly changed to fit usage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use sp_MSForEachDB.
For EXAMPLE, below, I have maybe 10 databases.  Two of them have my recurring "LogEntry" table.  If I wanted to get the count of rows per database, I can use the below.

NOTE, I have to check for "if exists" on the table, or the query will fail on databases without the table.

Instead of  SELECT, I could also push my counts to an aggregate database/table/column(s).

You can do whatever, the key is the sp_MSForEachDB calls.

```
EXECUTE sp_MSForEachDB 
        'USE ?;         IF (EXISTS (SELECT * 
                 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
                 WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = ''dbo''
                 AND  TABLE_NAME = ''LogEntry''))
BEGIN
    Select DB_NAME() AS DBName , COUNT(*) from dbo.LogEntry
END'
```